# Sudden spike in received traffic when connecting to the Tor Network

Tags: network, tor

Recently when using Tails, I've noticed that the traffic suddenly jumps to over 1TB when establishing a conenction to the Tor network after booting. It doesn't show up in Total Received and also, for some reason, tends to freeze the KiB Mem and KiB Swap counters on an instance of `top` that I'm running.

Is this normal? It has only recently started doing this and has not behaved like this before. It seems to happen only when connecting to the Tor network and not otherwise.

[image]

Comment: Please do not cross-post on StackExchange. Your other question is more properly located.